# How to block a User from logging in from multiple devices?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I want to implement a feature like if a User is logged in from PC1, It should not be allowed to login from PC2 or PC3.
Suggest us good approaches.

Comment: Why? What's the cost to you? or the risk?

Comment: Our customer require this, bro

Answer (score 2):

*There is no direct support for this feature.*

But you can try some workaround for this.

So Once User1 logs in you set some flag `isAlreadyLoggedIn` with User Id in a database table and set it to false once User1 logs out. You can capture the requested IP or Machine information also in this table to handle the request coming from different sources.
And you can check for this `isAlreadyLoggedIn` flag value in login controller method. You can also use Application level variable, `static` variable or you can write to some file or some azure blob storage for this.